# Multiple websites server side

Tags: express

With my express server I'm serving static files from 2 folders A and B:
- root/
-- static
--- A/
--- B/

The problem is that when someone calls **example.com/static/A/index.html**, if index.html contains absolute paths, it will fetch them in the server's root.

To be more precise:
If index.html contains src="main.js", it calls example.com/static/A or B/main.js.
If index.html contains src="/main.js", it calls example.com/main.js.

Is it possible to modify the second behavior to resolve / as /static/A or B/ without editing static files ?

Comment: Can you edit the nested static index pages? If yes, update your paths in them.

Comment: @TedFitzpatrick You mean replacing paths with a regex ? It should work but I wonder if there is a solution where I don't modify the static files.

Comment: its because you using absolute paths and not including the folder. Have you really done `app.use(express.static('./'));`? that may cause many issues

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Yes, for example if I replace /main.js by main.js in index.html everything works fine, But I'm trying to make it work in both cases.

Comment: You write an absolute path, you get the behaviour of an absolute path. Replacing all absolute paths by relative paths is the simplest, cleanest, straightforwardest and all round bestest solution. (If all paths were relative and you wanted them to behave like absolute paths, you could use the [`<base>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base).)

Comment: @Thomas I can't edit the absolute paths, some folders are webpack production builds etc..

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by using subdomains:

```js
let filesPath = path.join(__dirname, '../files')
app.set('subdomain offset', 1)
app.use('/', function(req,res,next) {
  if (req.subdomains.length != 1) {
    next()
  }
  req.url[0] = '.' //replace '/' with '.'
  req.url = req.subdomains[0] + req.url
  next()
})
app.use('/', express.static(filesPath))
```